# Q: Sitemap XML - Should I include the #Section links of my single-page website?

Tags: xml, web, sitemap

As the title suggests, I have a Website that is a single-page Site (homepage url only) for web design services purposes, with all of the menu links pointing to each of the #Sections on the main homepage itself.

**Question:** Should I include these #Section URL's in my website's Sitemap XML file?
Or, should I only list the primary domain name homepage of the site, and thats it?

**Bonus Question:** When linking to each Section via links in my Navbar, what format should I use?
Example: Either, `www dot mydomain dot com / #SectionID`(with the slash), OR
should I rather use `www dot mydomain dot com #SectionID` (without the slash)..?

Thank you in advance for help clarifying the correct answers to these questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not include hashes in your sitemap, as [already answered here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/22414/18342). So your sitemap should contain a single entry. Do you even need a sitemap then? Although it doesn't hurt, it will probably make no difference.

As for the bonus question, when linking to your page, you should include the slash before the hash, the `/` part is the *path* that needs to be present in every URL.

Check this URL validator: http://formvalidation.io/validators/uri/

- http://example.com/#foo is valid
- http://example.com#foo is not

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much Benjamin. Answer has been accepted and upvoted.

Comment: To be fairly honest, I now have a doubt regarding the necessary `/` before the `#`. Reading RFC 3986 makes me think that it *could* be valid (the above validator would be wrong, then), but I'm not sure whether I'm reading it properly or not . Anyway, by including the `/`, you're on the safe side. It's also worth noting that copy-pasting the second URL in the browser's address bar (at least in those I tried: Chrome, Firefox, Edge) makes it add the missing `/` anyway.